# ¿Cómo acceder en nodejs a mi base de datos mysql con varios usuarios que tienen distintos privilegios al mismo tiempo?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

```bash
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "-",
    user: "-",
    password: "-",
    database: "-"

});
```

nota: Esta seria mi conexión principal la idea es poder acceder con otros usuarios de distintos privilegios sin que se vea comprometido el cierre de la misma pues otro usuario estaría usando esta.
Existe alguna función propia de mysql2 para ello o tendría que implementar algo nuevo.

Comment: generalmente no quieres conectar directamente tu frontend con tu base de datos y menos con varios usuarios todos al mismo tiempo. Existen paquetes de node para conectarte con mysql pero no te recomiendo conectar mas de un usuario a la vez en tu mismo navegador.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias tendré en cuenta este consejo. Pero aun así espero una respuesta que me ayude a implementar una funcionalidad en concreto que tiene que ver con este tema.